Gem incompatible library version after installing rbenv
I'm trying to use rbenv, Bundler and CocoaPods for my xCode proj. Before I've never using rbenv and I'm not Ruby developer at all. I'm trying it to use only for tooling purposes to support my xCode proj.
Now after when I installed rbenv and installed required ruby version using it 3.2.1 I don't understand why I have error when I execute bundle install I get:
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------

```
LoadError: incompatible library version - /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/strscan-3.1.0/lib/strscan.bundle
  <internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  <internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:4:in `require_relative'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `require_relative'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych.rb:15:in `require_relative'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
  <internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  <internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:609:in `load_yaml'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:189:in `initialize'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:331:in `new'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:331:in `configuration'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:244:in `connection'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:90:in `initialize'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:254:in `new'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:254:in `block in fetchers'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:252:in `map'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:252:in `fetchers'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:397:in `block in remote_specs'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:396:in `remote_specs'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:129:in `specs'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:40:in `block in setup_solver'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:232:in `all_versions_for'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:49:in `block in setup_solver'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:151:in `versions_for'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:333:in `block in prepare_dependencies'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:328:in `each'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:328:in `map'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:328:in `prepare_dependencies'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:53:in `setup_solver'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:28:in `start'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:554:in `start_resolution'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:289:in `resolve'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:507:in `materialize'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:197:in `specs'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:231:in `ensure_specs_are_compatible!'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `block in run'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `open'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:71:in `run'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:23:in `install'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:261:in `block in install'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/settings.rb:131:in `temporary'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:260:in `install'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/exe/bundle:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
  /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.12/exe/bundle:33:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

```

## Environment

```
Bundler       2.4.12
  Platforms   ruby, arm64-darwin-23
Ruby          3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a9506d76391ac44bb2fe6e483fec952) [arm64-darwin-23]
  Full Path   /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/etc
RubyGems      3.3.7
  Gem Home    /Users/marcin/.gem
  Gem Path    /Users/marcin/.gem/ruby/3.1.0:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0:/Users/marcin/.gem
  User Home   /Users/marcin
  User Path   /Users/marcin/.gem/ruby/3.1.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/marcin/.gem/bin
OpenSSL       
  Compiled    OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024
  Loaded      OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024
  Cert File   /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem
  Cert Dir    /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3/certs
Tools         
  Git         2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.3.0
  chruby      not installed
```

## Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2023-04-11
Git SHA           e2cf278db1
Released Version  true
```

## Gemfile

### Gemfile

```ruby
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "fastlane"
gem "activesupport", "~> 7.0.8"
gem "cocoapods", "1.13.0"
gem "xcode-install"

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

### fastlane/Pluginfile

```ruby
gem 'fastlane-plugin-library_build', git: 'git@gitlab.eleader.biz:ios/fastlane/library-build.git'
gem 'fastlane-plugin-code_signing', git: 'git@gitlab.eleader.biz:ios/fastlane/code-signing.git'
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
<No /Users/marcin/develop/ftq/vas-base/Gemfile.lock found>
```

--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------

When I enter gem I get:
<internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/marcin/.gem/gems/strscan-3.1.0/lib/strscan.bundle (LoadError)
    from <internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych.rb:15:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:609:in `load_yaml'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:189:in `initialize'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73:in `new'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:38:in `run'
    from /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'

I'm very confused about gems how it connects to ruby and bundler. Bundler see gems like
  Config Dir  /Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/etc
RubyGems      3.3.7
  Gem Home    /Users/marcin/.gem
  Gem Path    /Users/marcin/.gem/ruby/3.1.0:/Users/marcin/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0:/Users/marcin/.gem
  User Home   /Users/marcin
  User Path   /Users/marcin/.gem/ruby/3.1.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/marcin/.gem/bin

And I think is is the source of the problem because it sees two different versions: 3.1.0 and 3.1.2. Should Gems version be the same as Ruby version (3.3.7 vs 3.1.2)?
Anybody Ruby Ninja here can guide me how to solve this kind of problems. It seems obvious that at some point I break something because of lack of specific knowledge but I don't know how to recover from this situation right now.
